# Starting container on demand

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, docker-swarm, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any way using k8s or swarm or any other option to automate the spawn of containers according to requests.

Part of my project is to send an event to an eventbus (rabbitMQ) which has a listener to the events once an event arrives then start a new container for each message.

The only option I found was to mount the host engine to the event listener container that and I don't really like this solution.

I would like an orchestrator to "listen" to the eventbus or to any other request queue container spawn requests and start them.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a broad question, there are many ways on you can accomplish this.

For example:

1. Write a simple bash script on an infinite loop that gets a message from RabbitMQ using another program (perhaps written [python](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) with Pika). As soon as it gets a message, issue a `docker run ...`
2. Write your own program with [Pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that waits for a message and then creates a pod in Kubernetes using the [python K8s client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).
3. You can also use any other language that has a client API for RabbitMQ, Docker, and/or Kubernetes.

Comment: My main language for this project is C# but language was never a problem,
Trying to make sure i understand, i am going to host the project on Azure\Google\AWS k8s service, will i still be able to run the options you mentioned ? as far as i know (and i am new to k8s) i can tell him which pods\containers to spawn but not according to events from lets say rabbitMQ.
Or i got it wrong ? i can run scripts on the k8s host ?

Comment: You can run on the k8s host or somewhere else where you have access to the `kube-apiserver`.  If you are using C#, you can try something like this: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rico, do i have access to kube-apiserver in the big cloud k8s providers (azure\google etc) ? or i need to host my own k8s cluster to be able to work with the k8s host ?

Comment: You do have access but only to its https endpoint. You don't have access to the server where its running. Access to https endpoint is all you would need.

Comment: The problem with all these solutions is that they don't utilize the things which come with e.g. Kubernetes. It would be ideal to make this work with pods so failures are easily mitigated